# Groups of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, usergroups

I have small project with users, users posts, friendships, comments.
I want to make groups of users. Can you help me make it? or send to make links to tutorials or books.
thank u so much

Comment: its pretty simple, google for association in rails you will get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a many-to-many relationship.  There are two ways to do this, and [this railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many) describes them (note that it is for Rails 2.x but the general idea carries over to Rails 3).

I'd also recommend looking at these two guides:

- [The `has_and_belongs_to_many` Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association)
- [The `has_many :through` Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)